# Mocking platform detection in Jest and React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Some of the code I am trying to test detects the platform, using, e.g.:

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
...

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Is there a sensible way to mock this with Jest and/or something else, so I can test both branches in one test run?

Or is the smart way to decouple it and put the platform into, e.g., a context variable? Although it always feels restructuring code to make it easier to test is something of a cheat.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This worked for me *(Jest 21.2.1, Enzyme 3.2.0)*:

```js
jest.mock('Platform', () => {
    const Platform = require.requireActual('Platform');
    Platform.OS = 'android';
    return Platform;
});
```

Put it either at the top of your test, or in [a `beforeAll`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#beforeallfn) for example.

Comment: Anyone having problems with flow: use `jest.requireActual` instead of `require.requireActual`

Comment: the downside for mock is that you can only test your app against one specific platform. iOS or Android. But what if you want to test how a specific component behaves on each platform?

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(Platform, 'OS', { get: jest.fn(() => 'ios') }) })`
works if a `beforeAll` statement

Comment: For me it only works when run in a jest setupFile (as can be set in the config in `setupFiles`). It didn't work in a `beforeAll` or at the top of a test because I use the check `Platform.OS === 'android'` in my code base and that is not changed.

Comment: @Orelus Your solution didn't work for me. Can you elaborate on why it should work please.

Comment: @Andru I modified the code (so it's no longer in a `beforeAll`), but here is what works for me https://www.codepile.net/pile/Yr5DkK4n

Comment: This solution does not work anymore after react-native 0.61. See Simon Gamble answer or these links https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26710#issuecomment-552842415 https://altany.github.io/react-native/0.61/jest/mocking/upgrade/2020/01/25/mocking-react-native-0.61-modules-with-jest.html https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26579#issuecomment-535244001

Answer (score 36):

For everyone looking for this, what it helped me was the following:

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform', () => ({
    OS: 'android', // or 'ios'
    select: () => null
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I hadn't thought to check Utilities for Platform and couldn't find it.  For anyone trying to mock these modules, note that mocking the full path the module is required in >0.61, due to the removal of Haste.

Comment: This did not work for me, but check my answer for how I managed to mock platform detection with 0.61.

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm that this works on react-native 0.64.3

Answer (score 13):

The way that I achieved mocking setting the platform was just set it directly in the tests:

```js
it('should only run for Android', () => {
  Platform.OS = 'android'; // or 'ios'

  // For my use case this module was failing on iOS
  NativeModules.MyAndroidOnlyModule = {
    fetch: jest.fn(
      (url, event) => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(event.body))
    ),
  }; 
  return myParentFunction().then(() => {
    expect(NativeModules.MyAndroidOnlyModule.fetch.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(fetch.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

This would setup the platform to only run on Android during tests to make sure that my function was calling only specific functions. My function that was wrapped in platform dependent compilation looked like:

```js
export default function myParentFunction() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    return fetch();
  }
  return NativeModules.MyAndroidOnlyModule.fetch();
}
```

I would suggest just creating two different tests one with the platform set to iOS and the other to Android since ideally a function should only have one responsibility. However, I'm sure you can use this to run the first test, dynamically set the platform and run test number two all in one function.

Comment: wouldn't this approach change the Platform.OS for all the tests?

Comment: I guess you could just set it back, const previousPlatform = Platform.OS; at the end of test Platform.OS = previousPlatform;

Answer (score 12):

I implemented a small mock that allows you to change `Platform` during tests in the same test file.

Add this to your [jest setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array)

```js
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform', () => {
  let platform = {
    OS: 'ios',
  }

  const select = jest.fn().mockImplementation((obj) => {
    const value = obj[platform.OS]
    return !value ? obj.default : value
  })

  platform.select = select

  return platform
});
```

Then you can easily change `Platform` in your test. If you are using `Platform.select` it will also work as expected!

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

describe('When Android', () => {
  it('should ...', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'android'
    ...
  })
})

describe('When iOS', () => {
  it('should ...', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'ios'
    ...
  })
})
```

Comment: Best answer for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

**React Native 0.61 update**

Though the accepted solution works for versions of React Native 0.60 and below, React Native 0.61 has dropped Haste support and this gives an error.

I was able to mock platform detection following the implementation described in this [blog post](https://altany.github.io/react-native/0.61/jest/mocking/upgrade/2020/01/25/mocking-react-native-0.61-modules-with-jest.html).

Practically, [according to the React team](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26579#issuecomment-535244001), we now have to mock the react-native interface. So, you can create a *`react-native.js`* file inside the *`tests/__mocks__`* folder and add this code to mock Platform:

```
import * as ReactNative from "react-native";

export const Platform = {
  ...ReactNative.Platform,
  OS: "ios",
  Version: 123,
  isTesting: true,
  select: objs => objs[Platform.OS]
};

export default Object.setPrototypeOf(
  {
    Platform
  },
  ReactNative
);
```

With this implementation, we can now simply overwrite the OS before running the test like:

```
Platform.OS = 'android'
```

Answer (score 7):

Since the other answers will not work if you want to mock different OSs *in the same test suite* and *in one test run*, here's another way. Instead of using `Platform.OS` directly in your code, define a helper function somewhere and use that to get references to the OS in your components:

in 'helpers.js':

```js
export function getOS() {
  return Platform.OS;
}
```

in your component:

```js
import * as helpers from './helpers';
render() {
    if (helpers.getOS() === 'android') {// do something}
}
```

This function *can* then be mocked it in your tests, e.g.

```js
import * as helpers from './helpers';

// ...

it('does something on Android', () => {
  jest.spyOn(helpers, 'getOS').mockImplementation(() => 'android');
  // ...
}

it('does something else on iOS', () => {
  jest.spyOn(helpers, 'getOS').mockImplementation(() => 'ios');
  // ...
}
```

Credit for the idea goes to [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1370#issuecomment-277991682).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the error `"getOS" is read-only.` on the line with `mockImplementationOnce`

Comment: @Andru thx for the notice, this was outdated. Just updated it to what is currently working for me (RN 0.59, Jest 24).

Comment: Thanks @d0gb3r7 for adjusting it that quickly!

Comment: Mocking something like `platform.system()` in Python (with any test runner) is trivial. With jest (using typescript), after a few hours of trying with the army of mock* utilities, I ended up mocking `os.homedir()` with the method mentioned here. I may lack the experience with Jest and JS/TS testing, but the amount of options on offer (for just temporarily switching out a name from a stdlib module), of which pretty much none works easy/intuitive/as expected was a bit surprising and a rather bad experience.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me...

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform', () => {
  const Platform = require.requireActual(
    'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform'
  )
  Platform.OS = 'android'
  return Platform
})
```

Answer (score 5):

this is the mock you need:

```
const mockPlatform = OS => {    
  jest.resetModules();  
  jest.doMock("Platform", () => ({ OS, select: objs => objs[OS] }));
};
```

with it you can do the following:

```
it("my test on Android", () => {
  mockPlatform("android");
});

it("my test on iOS", () => {
  mockPlatform("ios");
});
```

That way you can have tests for both platforms

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The platform won't change from the default `iOS`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the solution from this github issue https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1370#issuecomment-352597475

I moved the jest config from `package.json` to separate files. 
So far everything seems to work great, including:
a) the right file is imported according to the platform. For example on ios: .ios.tsx, then .native.tsx then .tsx
b) PLATFORM.IOS returns true when running test-ios, no need to mock anything

```js
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config config/jest.desktop.json",
  "test-ios": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config config/jest.ios.json",
  "test-android": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config config/jest.android.json"
}

// config/jest.web.json
{
...
}

// config/jest.ios.json
{
...
  "preset": "react-native",
  "haste": {
    "defaultPlatform": "ios",
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios",
      "native"
    ],
    "providesModuleNodeModules": [
      "react-native"
    ]
  },
}

// config/jest.android.json
{
...
  "preset": "react-native",
  "haste": {
    "defaultPlatform": "android",
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios",
      "native"
    ],
    "providesModuleNodeModules": [
      "react-native"
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [jest.doMock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) and [jest.resetModules](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestresetmodules)

```js
jest.resetModules()
jest.doMock('react-native', () => ({ Platform: { OS: 'android' }}))
```

Answer (score 2):

for newer version

"react-native": "0.62.2"

"enzyme": "^3.11.0"

"jest": "24.5.0"

Put it at the top of your test

```
Object.defineProperty(Platform, 'OS', { get: jest.fn(() => 'ios') })
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution for individual test cases

Answer (score 2):

`jest: ^26.5.3`

See bottom of this [article](https://altany.github.io/react-native/0.61/jest/mocking/upgrade/2020/01/25/mocking-react-native-0.61-modules-with-jest.html)

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

describe('Android', () => {
  it('renders Element if Android', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'android';
    renderIfAndroid();
    expect(wrapper.find(Element)).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});

describe('IOS', () => {
  it('renders Element if IOS', () => {
    Platform.OS = 'ios';
    renderIfIOS();
    expect(wrapper.find(Element)).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem in the "import" method, check this:

```
const isAndroid = require('app/helpers/is_android');

//import isAndroid from 'app/helpers/is_android'
```

with "import" this will not work, need to use "require".

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});

it("should be true when Android", () => {
  jest.mock('Platform', () => {
    return { OS: 'android' };
  });

  expect(isAndroid).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import SmartText from "../SmartText";

describe("markdown smart text component", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  it("renders with props on ios", () => {
    jest.mock("Platform", () => {
      return { OS: "ios" };
    });
    expect(
      renderer.create(<SmartText title="code ios" code />).toJSON()
    ).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it("renders with props on android", () => {
    jest.mock("Platform", () => {
      return { OS: "android" };
    });
    expect(
      renderer.create(<SmartText title="code android" code />).toJSON()
    ).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To change Platform *only for a specific test*, the following can be used:

```js
  test('Platform should be Android', () => {
    jest.doMock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform', () => ({
      OS: 'android',
    }));

    expect(Platform.OS).toBe('android');

    // restore the previous value 'ios' for Platform.OS
    jest.dontMock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock whatever you want from `React-Native` like this:

```js
describe('notifications actions tests', () => {
  let Platform;


  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
          Platform: {
           ... 
        }));


    Platform = require('react-native').Platform; // incase u would like to refer to Platform in your tests
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't that make it permanent? i.e., won't that mean I need to "unmock" in an `afterEach`? Is that possible?

Comment: Hmm, no this doesn't work. `jest.mock` gets hoisted so it's not in `beforeEach`, so it's run before everything. A viable option seems to be monkey patching `RN.Platform.OS` object before a test. Or decoupling platform into the context.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking out to mock `Platform.select`. The below code can fix your issue.

```
const mockedData = 'MOCKED-DATA'
jest.mock('react-native', () => ({

    Platform: {
        select: jest.fn(() => {
            return { mockedData  } // Your Mocked Value
        }),
    }
}));
```

And To mock both `OS` and `Platform`. Please refer below code.

```
 jest.mock('Platform', () => ({
      OS: 'android', // or 'ios'
      select: () => 'mocked-value'
 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the Platform object using `jest.replaceProperty`. For more info you can visit https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value

```js
import { Platform } from "react-native";

        
it("ios test", async () => {
    
  jest.replaceProperty(Platform, "OS", "ios");
        
  // Your test
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to mock the module and import it into your test. Then you can use `mockImplementation` to set the it to either `android` or `ios`

```js
import reactNative from 'react-native';
jest.mock('react-native', () = > jest.fn();

it('is android', () => {
  reactNative.mockImplementation(()=>({Platform:{OS: 'android'}}))
  //test the android case
})

it('is android', ()=>{
  reactNative.mockImplementation(()=>({Platform: { OS: 'io' }}))
  //test the ios case
})
```

Comment: I tried this method but I get `_reactNative2.default.mockImplementation is not a function`. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: This wont work, since it's defined as `ReactNative.Platform.OS`, not just `ReactNative.Platform`

Comment: still don't working `_reactNative2.default.mockImplementation is not a function`

Answer (score -2):

OS can be set directly for each test

```js
 test('android', () => {
     Platform.OS = 'android'
     const component = renderer.create(<Component />).toJSON()
     expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
 })
 test('ios', () => {
     Platform.OS = 'ios'
     const component = renderer.create(<Component />).toJSON()
     expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
 })
```

Comment: Downvotes with no explanation doesn't help anyone. Please explain

Comment: tests pass but from test coverage (branch column) it seems that it does'nt test for both platforms