# React Native: Jest mocking Platform

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, snapshot, babel-jest

When writing unit tests for a React Native project I want to be able to test different snapshots based on different platforms.

I first tried `jest.mock` to mock `Platform` but seems to be async. This approach does work when I have two separate files, but I'd prefer to keep everything in one file if possible.

I tried `jest.doMock` because of this snippet from the documentation:

> When using babel-jest, calls to mock will automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block. Use this method if you want to explicitly avoid this behavior.
>   https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options

However I'm still seeing undesirable results. When I `console.log` in the android test I see that `Platform.OS` is whatever I set the first `doMock` to be.

I also tried wrapping the mock in a `beforeEach` in a `describe` becasue I thought that might help with scoping
http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/setup-teardown.html#scoping

```js
 describe('ios test', () => {
  it('renders ui correctly', () => {
    jest.doMock('Platform', () => {
      const Platform = require.requireActual('Platform');
      Platform.OS = 'ios';
      return Platform;
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />);
    const tree = renderer.create(wrapper).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});

describe('android test', () => {
  it('renders ui correctly', () => {
    jest.doMock('Platform', () => {
      const Platform = require.requireActual('Platform');
      Platform.OS = 'android';
      return Platform;
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />);
    const tree = renderer.create(wrapper).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Any ideas on how I can change the mock Platform for tests in the same file?

Comment: Anyone having problems with flow: use `jest.requireActual` instead of `require.requireActual`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of suggestions on how to solve this problem in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161416), but none of them worked for me either, given the same requirements you have (tests for different OSs in the *same* suite file and in *one* test run).

I eventually worked around it with a somewhat clunky trivial helper function that *can* be mocked as expected in tests – something like:

```js
export function getOS() {
  return Platform.OS;
}
```

Use it instead of `Platform.OS` in your code, and then simply mock it in your tests, e.g.

```js
it('does something on Android', () => {
  helpers.getOS = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => 'android');
  // ...
}
```

That did the trick; credit for the idea is due to [this guy](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1370#issuecomment-277991682).

Comment: Even in 2021, I think this is the best answer and best choice for this issue.