# How to run Jest with React-Native with Android only

Tags: jestjs, react-native

When I run `npm test` I get this error :

```
Test suite failed to run

    RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects `Podfile` and have run `pod install`.
```

I want to use Jest to run tests for Android plateform only because I'm not developing for iOS.

Comment: I'm not sure.Try to use index.android.js instead of single file index.js. And get the file extension of index.android.js file in your test folder and try to run npm test.Check whether it's work.

Comment: @priyanga still got the same error after doing it.

Comment: For this issue,my solution was to run.Go to the directory 1.cd ios/ 2.pod update 3.pod install (or)  try to link the library like  react-native link.

Comment: Try to follow the link as given below.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161416/mocking-platform-detection-in-jest-and-react-native

Comment: ```
jest.mock('Platform', () => {
  const Platform = require.requireActual('Platform');
  Platform.OS = 'android';
  return Platform;
});

import LoginScreen from '../../components/login'

test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<LoginScreen />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

```

Now the error is the same but related to gradle file :
```
 RNFirebase core module was not found natively on Android, ensure you have correctly added the RNFirebase and Firebase gradle dependencies to your `android/app/build.gradle` file.
```

Comment: But this `RNFirebase not found` problem is because jest is not providing a mock for 3rd party modules.

Answer (score -1):

I added this code on top of my test file to mock all the test on Android :

```
jest.mock('Platform', () => {
  const Platform = require.requireActual('Platform');
  Platform.OS = 'android';
  return Platform;
})
```

**IMPORTANT :** It has to be on ***top*** of all the test functions