# Can't find module './Libraries/Utilities/Platform' from 'node_modules/react-native/index.js' react-native?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm unable to [mock platform selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161416/mocking-platform-detection-in-jest-and-react-native) due to jest being unable to find the module

**Error Message 1**

```
 tests/__tests__/base.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module './Libraries/Utilities/Platform' from 'node_modules/react-native/index.js'

    Require stack:
      src/theme/index.js
      src/tools/index.js
      src/db/models/subscription.js
      src/db/realm.js
      tests/realm.js
      tests/__tests__/base.test.js


    However, Jest was able to find:
        'Libraries/Utilities/Platform.android.js'
        'Libraries/Utilities/Platform.d.ts'
        'Libraries/Utilities/Platform.ios.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'mjs', 'cjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'].
```

When removing the `...ReactNative.Platform` line from **jest.setup.js** the following error occours:

**Error Message 2**

```
    Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

      13 |       },
      14 |       NativeModules: {
    > 15 |         ...ReactNative.NativeModules,
```

I have tried adding `'^Libraries/Utilities/Platform$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.android.js',` to the moduleNameMapper

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!react-native)/.+'],
  setupFiles: ['./tests/jest.setup.js'],
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^react-native$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native',
  },
}
```

**jest.setup.js**

```
import * as ReactNative from 'react-native'

jest.doMock('react-native', () => {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf(
    {
      Dimensions: {
        get: () => ({ width: 414, height: 896 }),
      },
      Platform: {
        ...ReactNative.Platform,
        OS: 'android',
        select: jest.fn((selector) => selector),
      },
      NativeModules: {
        ...ReactNative.NativeModules,
        SettingsManager: {
          settings: {
            AppleLocale: 'en_US',
          },
        },
        I18nManager: {
          localeIdentifier: 'en_US',
        },
      },
    },
    ReactNative
  )
})
```

Do I need a [module resolver plugin?](https://github.com/expo/web-examples/issues/73#issuecomment-621078860)